# jQuery UI api - animation on selected tabs stops

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

i'm targetting the selected navigation tab in the jQuery UI tabs widget as :

```
$('$tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
var choosen = ui.index;
$('#$tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav').find('li:eq(' + choosen + ')').stop(true, true).animate({
'width': '350px'
}, 100);
});
```

It works ! but only one time, once it has looped, it stops animating...
any idea ?
thank you
TO be really clear, here is an example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/moabi/ALYXs/5/

you'll see the animation on the tabs stopping after they have been visited...

Comment: You don't put the width back of the other tabs? You can't animate something that is already 350px width, to 350px width.